# instance methods from class methods swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

I have a class TestClass and a class & instance method inside it

```
class  TestClass {

    class func classMethod(){

       print("how do i call instance method from here")

    }

    func instanceMethod(){

        print("call this instance method")

    }


}
```

My question is how do i call that `instanceMethod` from `classMethod`??

One way i have noticed is

```
class func classMethod(){

   TestClass().instanceMethod()

}
```

But,Is this the good way to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do rarely makes any sense from a design perspective.

By definition, an `instance method` operates on an `instance` of an object.
For example, it might require access to some instance members, or somehow meddle with the state of the object you call the method on.

`class` methods on the other hand do not require an instance to be able to call them - and should in general only operate on the given parameters, not be dependant on shared state.

If you need to call `instanceMethod()` in `classMethod()`, and `instanceMethod()` does not require any state - why is it not also a `class` method, or a (global) pure function?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the instance object as a parameter to the class method, and then call the instance method of the object:

```
class  TestClass {

    class func classMethod(obj:TestClass){

       print("how do i call instance method from here")
       obj.instanceMethod()
    }

    func instanceMethod(){

        print("call this instance method")
    }
}
```

Comment: At that point, the class method may as well be made into an instance method

Answer (score 0):

To call the instance method, you need an instance of `TestClass`.  That's what `TestClass()` is getting you when you call `TestClass().instanceMethod()`.

If you want to call it from a specific instance, you could pass it in as a parameter to the class function: `class func classMethodUsingInstance(instance: TestClass)`

If you don't need a specific instance for `instanceMethod()`, maybe consider making it a class method as well.